# How do I set an environment variable?

Tags: npm

In bash I can see npm environment variables with `npm run env`.  `USER=brianmackey` is one such environment variable.  How can I set an environment variable, say `USER=billybob`?

I know I can use `npm config set <key> <value> [--global]`.  Is key+value always/in any case an environment variable?  Can I set the environment variables in session?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Single Command**

If you want to set environment variables for a single node command, you can simply do this:

```
$ USER=billybob node server.js
```

**Loaded for each session**

If you want to permanently set that environment variable for your user, edit your `~/.bash_profile` and add the following line:

```
export USER="billybob"
```

This will automatically set the given environment variable each time you create a new terminal session.

**Existing for the entire current session**

Lastly, if you want to set the environment variable only for the current session, just run it as it's own command:

```
$ USER=billybob
$ node app.js # user is billybob
$ node app.js # user is still billybob
```

When you exit the session, these temporarily set environment variables will be cleared.

Comment: Very helpful.   Can `npm config` work with environment variables as well?

Comment: `npm config set <key> <value> --global` will not affect system environment variables. npm has it's own storage for these globally stored key-value pairs.